# Flutter: how to add an "if" logic inside of a build function in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have the following in a build function and I only want it to show if the logic is correct

```
if (!isKeyBoardVisible) 
     SizedBox(height: 13.0),
     buildApplyButton(),
     SizedBox(height: 20.0,)
```

However, the above statement only worked for  the first size box..

How can I make it entire 3 statements

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the spread operator

```
if (!isKeyBoardVisible)
  ...[ 
     SizedBox(height: 13.0),
     buildApplyButton(),
     SizedBox(height: 20.0,)
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 isKeyBoardVisible
                  ? Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(height: 13.0),
                        buildApplyButton(),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  : Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(height: 13.0),
                        buildApplyButton(),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        )
                      ],
                    )
```

: is else part of ternary operator you can put your else part there

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine your *if* with the spread operator:

```dart
final x = [
  if (true)
    ...[
      42,
      42
    ],
];
```